# Flutter: cloud_firestore_web-3.1.1 Error: Method not found: 'FallThroughError'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

This problem started to occur after updating flutter, and dependencies, when launching in Chorme(web)

> sdk: '>=3.0.0-35.0.dev <4.0.0'
>
> cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
> firebase_core: ^2.4.0
> cloud_firestore: ^4.2.0
> firebase_auth: ^4.2.1

Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-3.1.1/lib/src/utils/web_utils.dart:71:13: Error: Method not found: 'FallThroughError'.
throw FallThroughError();
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is a known issue:
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10140